# Obtaining GPS data every 1 second

Tags: android, gps, location

I am wondering if there is a way to gather GPS location data every second?  My understanding is is the locationListener is only called when the location is changed.  I have a thread running every second in this manner:

```
private void startTimer() {
    _mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    _mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1000);   
}

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        _mHandler.postDelayed(this, _interval);

         // work
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

You can set the mintime to 1000ms for location updates in the method requestLocationUpdates.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to query the location every second? register a listener and set up synchronized members to hold the last location and query them in your 1-second-interval thread.